# FBSession.m Crashes in iOS6.0 with FacebookSdk.framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios6

I am using new FacebookSdk and My app is crashing when running in iOS 6.0.Here is crash log

```
*** Assertion failure in -[FBSession close], /Users/jacl/src/release/ios-sdk/src/FBSession.m:404
2012-12-12 12:48:49.993 localfave[1406:1d903] uncaughtExceptionHnadler -- Exception FBSession: should only be used from a single thread
2012-12-12 12:48:49.996 test[1406:1d903] Stack trace: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02d6b02e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01cd6e7e objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02d6ae78 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x0176cf35 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   localfave                           0x000f6e1d -[FBSession close] + 177
    5   localfave                           0x000f753e +[FBSession setActiveSession:] + 50
    6   localfave                           0x000fa6ee +[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:allowLoginUI:allowSystemAccount:isRead:defaultAudience:completionHandler:] + 230
    7   test                           0x000f7408 +[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:] + 82
    8   test                           0x00002fc6 -[AppDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:] + 166
    9   test                           0x0008adc5 -[FacebookLoginViewController registerFacebook:] + 165
    10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01cea705 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    11  UIKit                               0x00c21920 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
    12  UIKit                               0x00c218b8 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    13  UIKit                               0x00ce2671 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    14  UIKit                               0x00ce2bcf -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
    15  UIKit                               0x00ce1d38 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 546
    16  UIKit                               0x00c5133f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 846
    17  UIKit                               0x00c51552 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273
    18  UIKit                               0x00c2f3aa -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 436
    19  UIKit                               0x00c20cf8 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x03057df9 _PurpleEventCallback + 339
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x03057ad0 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x02ce0bf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x02ce0962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x02d11bb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x02d10f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x02d10e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x030567e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x03056668 GSEventRun + 104
    29  UIKit                               0x00c1e65c UIApplicationMain + 1211
    30  test                           0x00002545 main + 213
    31  test                           0x00002425 start + 53
)
```

And Code is

```
/*
 * Opens a Facebook session and optionally shows the login UX.
 */
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState state,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                                             [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                 state:state
                                                                 error:error];
                                         }];
}

/*
 * Callback for session changes.
 */
```

Please Help!

Comment: now in ios6, the new framework has been introduced and that is socialframework.so no need to create lots of methods for facebook implementation.https://github.com/yashesh87/Social-Framework-iOS6/tree/master/SocialNetwrking this link will help you

Comment: but that project is already having this socialFramework

Comment: have you made socialframework optional from required??

Answer (score 0):

just write this code where you want to post on facebook and discard everyfunction that you have made for facebook integration and i think you have imported #import  in .h file.

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
                NSLog(@"ResultCancelled");
            } else

            {
                NSLog(@"Success");
            }

            [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
        };
        controller.completionHandler =myBlock;
        [controller setInitialText:@"Awesome App"];
        [controller addImage:photoImage.image];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
```

let me know it is working or not....!!!

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: But it is not allowing me to login

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Social, Accounts, AdSupport frameworks and they are optional.
Copy FacebookSDK.framework, FacebookSDKResources.bundle, FBUserSettingsViewResources.bundle.
They can be found on Facebook Developers for iOS web page. If the problem occurs again, try deleting all the frameworks and add them again. This is a framework problem, not with the code.

Comment: I am not getting the solution. I added frameworks again but not working